# Nodejs Google Oauth2 callback returns http 500 error

Tags: node.js, google-api-client, google-oauth

I am trying to practice Google Apis and learn express
I am following the Google Oauth2 implementation using Nodejs . Please follow the [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#usage)

I am able to generate the URL which would redirect me to Google website and once the permissions are granted the callback always fails. I think the my callback route function is never invoked following are the values in the url

I would have the following in the url

http://localhost:3000/googlecallback?code=[my code]

and the get route code is as below

```js
app.use("/googlecallback", function(req, res) {
  var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
  var session = req.session;
  var code = req.query.code;
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if (!err) {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      session["tokens"] = tokens;
      res.send('User Authenticated');
    } else {
      res.send('User Authentication failed');
    }
  });
});

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.